# js increment date by 3 hours when i put exact time in date

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const date = new Date(2022, 4, 18, 16, 50);
```

Why does this return the time reduced by three hours?

I get this `"2022-05-18T13:50:00.000Z"` instead of this `"2022-05-18T16:50:00.000Z"` which I expected to get when I print this to console using `console.log(date)`.

Comment: Timezones, it returns `2022-05-18T14:50:00.000Z` here.

Answer (score 1):

> why does this return the time reduced by three hours?

It doesn't, it gives you exactly the time you asked for — in your local time. But then you're getting a string from it in a way that gives you a string in UTC, not local time (the `Z` at the end tells you it's UTC). Apparently there's a three-hour difference as of that date/time between your local timezone and UTC.

If you want to work in local time, use `toLocaleString` to get a string formatted according to your current locale and using your timezone. If you want a string like the one you got, but in your local timezone, as far as I know you have to build it yourself.

If you want to work in UTC, build the date using the [`UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) function: `new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 4, 18, 16, 50));`

Answer (score 0):

it's because of your timezone!
for example:

```
let d = new Date(2022, 4, 18, 16, 50);
d.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `Date()` constructor with individual components it will interpret those in your local time. See point `5` on this [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

But when you print int without `toLocaleString()` it will return the UTC time instead. Depending on your time zone this is more or less far away from what you have entered.